# How to return the tree node by index when tree nodes have subtree size?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, tree

Say I have this piece of demo data:

```
{
  size: 100,
  type: 'container',
  list: [
    {
      size: 30,
      type: 'container',
      list: [
        {
          size: 10,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        },
        {
          size: 15,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        },
        {
          size: 25,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      size: 50,
      type: 'container',
      list: [
        {
          size: 20,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
        },
        {
          size: 25,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        },
        {
          size: 25,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        }
        ,
        {
          size: 30,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      size: 20,
      type: 'container',
      list: [
        {
          size: 5,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5]
        },
        {
          size: 15,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*Note, I just filled the so-called "leaf" nodes with integers to show their array positions. But they could be filled with any JavaScript objects (Arrays, objects, strings, numbers, etc.). The leaf nodes can have max 32 items, but I don't think that really matters for this question. The container nodes can only have 32 direct children as well.*

How do you say `getLeafContaining(tree, index)`, where it will return you the leaf which has the item at the global `index`, as well as the relative index. I say "global index" because this is the index of the leaf node if you were to take all of the leaf nodes as sequential.

What I have done so far is this:

```js
const getLeafContaining = (tree, index) => {
  if (index > tree.size - 1) {
    return { node: null, index: -1 }
  }

  let nodes = [tree]
  let startSize = 0
  a:
  while (true) {
    b:
    for (let i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; i++) {
      let node = nodes[i]
      let endSize = startSize + node.size
      if (startSize <= index && index <= endSize) {
        if (node.type == 'container') {
          nodes = node.list
          break b
        } else {
          let relativeIndex = index - startSize
          return { node, index: relativeIndex }
        }
      } else {
        startSize = endSize
      }
    }
  }
}

const tree = {
  size: 100,
  type: 'container',
  list: [
    {
      size: 30,
      type: 'container',
      list: [
        {
          size: 10,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        },
        {
          size: 15,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        },
        {
          size: 25,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      size: 50,
      type: 'container',
      list: [
        {
          size: 20,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
        },
        {
          size: 25,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        },
        {
          size: 25,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
        }
        ,
        {
          size: 30,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      size: 20,
      type: 'container',
      list: [
        {
          size: 5,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5]
        },
        {
          size: 15,
          type: 'leaf',
          list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(getLeafContaining(tree, 22))
```

It seems to be correct but I can't tell. How to you robustly implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by "relative index"?

Comment: It's weird that you're not using a standard recursive approach on a tree

Comment: The relative index is the index relative to the final leaf, which contains up to 32 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's incorrect, `index <= endSize` should be `index < endSize`. In the worst case this would lead to an infinite loop on an empty node.

Also a recursive solution would have been much simpler than the iterative version:

```
const getLeafContaining = (tree, index) => {
  if (index < tree.size) {
    if (node.type == 'leaf') {
      return { node, index };
    } else if (node.type == 'container') {
      let before = 0
      for (const node of nodes) {
        const after = before + node.size;
        if (index < after) {
          return getLeafContaining(node, index - before);
        }
        before = after;
      }
    }
  }
  return { node: null, index: -1 }
}
```

An alternative to the accumulating `before` sum would be to decrement `index`:

```
      for (const node of nodes) {
        if (index < node.size) {
          return getLeafContaining(node, index);
        }
        index -= node.size;
      }
```